# How to "put" current selection into * in Vim?

Tags: vim

Okey, the title definitely needs work, but you Vimmers out there, may already have a clue of what I'm aiming at.

I recently found myself using Vim's `*` function often (pressing the `*` key to fast forward search for some words). Is there a way to put the current visual selection (usually consisting of two or three words) into with `*` and then to use the `*` key to toggle through the buffer for it?

*The question body is goona need some work too :-)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command that comes with the help of `vim`, it's like:

```
:vmap X y/<C-R>"<CR>
```

What does it mean?

With some text selected in visual mode, press `X` and the map yanks it to the unnamed register (`y`), begins a search command (`/`), yanks the content of the unnamed register into the text to search (`<C-R>"`) and begins the search with `<CR>`. After it you can use the common `*` to following terms.